# Gnuplot Version 5.4 patchlevel 1: plot several datasets with single title (legend entry)

Tags: gnuplot, title

I want to plot several lines. However I want all of them to have the same style and create a single entry in the legend.

When I use

```
splot '-' with lines
```

with these data

```
0.0 0.0 0.0
0.1 0.1 0.1
0.0 0.1 0.0


0.2 0.2 0.2
0.3 0.3 0.3
0.3 0.2 0.3
e
```

everything is as I expect. Also as expected, any style is applied to all the lines.

However if I try to add a title

```
splot '-' with lines title "myTitle"
```

an entry in the legend for each one is generated.

[image]

How can I have a single legend entry?

[Notice that I need two newlines between the data sets, because I want different lines and not a grid]
[I am using Gnuplot Version 5.4 patchlevel 1]

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Which gnuplot version are you working with? Please edit your question and add your resulting graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creation of duplicate key entries in this case was an unintended consequence of an intended change.  See [Issue #2380 duplicate titles in key](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/2380/).  For the specific case here where the plot command requests a title by providing a quoted string, the old behavior will be restored in release 5.4.2 - you will only get a single entry in the key even though multiple data sets are plotted.

FYI - the change was introduced because it is now possible to generate a distinct title for each data set in the file.  However it is not particularly useful to have multiple titles that are all the same.  The intended use is illustrated by

```
plot 'file.dat' using 1:2 title sprintf("Data set %d", column(-2))
```

where `column(-2)` returns the index number of this data set.  In earlier gnuplot versions you would have to iterate explicitly over the index number

```
plot for [index=1:*] 'file.dat' using 1:2 title sprintf("Data set %d",index)
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful clarification. In that case, I will not implement any temporary workaround and wait for the next release.

Comment: Dear @Ethan, if I'm not mistaken 5.4.2 is already out, but the new behaviour is still there. From your answer I suppose you are one of the developed (in that case, great job!). Do you know if the plan is still there to revert back to the original behaviour? If not, I will modify my code. Thanks!

Comment: It is fixed in 5.4.2.  See new answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I tested with gnuplot 5.2.6, and there you don't see this behaviour. Pretty, strange. I'm not sure why this has changed.
With gnuplot 5.4 you can work around for example with the following. Check `help keyentry`.

**Code:**

```
### only one key for a dataset separated by two empty lines
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0.0 0.0 0.0
0.1 0.1 0.1
0.0 0.1 0.0


0.2 0.2 0.2
0.3 0.3 0.3
0.3 0.2 0.3
EOD

splot $Data    w l ls 1 notitle, \
      keyentry w l ls 1 title "only one title"
### end of code
```

**Edit:** (alternative solution without `keyentry` and repeating the linestyle)

```
myTitle(i) = i==0 ? "only one title" : ""
splot for [i=0:*] $Data index i w l ls 1 title myTitle(i)
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It is a pity as one needs to rewrite all the formatting options in both lines.

Comment: @marco I hope there is a better solution... I really don't know what the reasoning behind this is. .... Well, maybe there is a slightly better solution, see edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Update showing result in version 5.4.2**

```
### only one key for a dataset separated by two empty lines
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0.0 0.0 0.0
0.1 0.1 0.1
0.0 0.1 0.0


0.2 0.2 0.2
0.3 0.3 0.3
0.3 0.2 0.3
EOD

set title sprintf("Gnuplot version %.1f.%s", GPVAL_VERSION, GPVAL_PATCHLEVEL)

splot $Data with lines title "myTitle"
### end of code
```

[image]